# Cannot retarget VS 2010 project to .Net 3.5 after installing SP 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to add unit tests to a sharepoint solution in VS2010. I have a test project but I cannot retarget the project to .Net 3.5 even after installing SP 1 for VS2010. Please advise.

Comment: I was able to retarget a Sharepoint MSTest project finally by reinstalling VS2010 then reapplying SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that worked for me to make Unit tests work with Sharepoint:

- Install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1
- Create a new C# unit test project
- In Project Properties change Application ->Target Framework to 3.5 and Build -> Platform Target to x64
- In Test - Edit Test Settings - local testsettings - Hosts tab : change run tests setting to "Run in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine"

Regards